# How to filter an array using an array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nspredicate

I have three types of custom classes (see below) and three arrays componentList, componentGroupList and componentGroupItemList. Arrays are not linked, each of them contain all objects. I need to filter specific component, all its related groups and all their related items.

Now, I know how to filter componentList using @"componentId==123" and get desired component object. I can also filter its groups from componentGroupList using the same predicate,  because ComponentGroup object contains the same componentId key. However, I don't know how to filter related ComponentGroupItem objects from componentGroupItemList.

Currently, I have filtered array containing ComponentGroup objects, and I would like to filter componentGroupItemList using that array. Is it possible, or do I need to extract all "groupId" values from filteredComponentGroupList into a string and then make some predicate?

The classes:

```
@interface Component : NSObject

  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *componentId;
  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;

@end

@interface ComponentGroup : NSObject

  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *groupId;
  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *componentId;
  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;

@end

@interface ComponentGroupItem : NSObject

  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *itemId;
  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *groupId;
  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to extract the group ids first

```
NSArray *groupIds = [filteredComponentGroupList valueForKey:@"groupId"];
```

and use that for a predicate

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"groupId IN %@", groupIds];
NSArray *filteredComponentGroupItemList = [componentGroupItemList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Answer (score 2):

At a first glance your data structure seems a bit redundant, but I guess you have thought it through.

If I understand your requirements correctly, you have an array of component groups already filtered (let's call it `filteredComponentGroups`) and you wish to filter another array (`componentGroupItemList`) using `filteredComponentGroups`.

In that case you can use the `IN` operator of `NSPredicate` and construct the array of IDs with `valueForKey:` on the array. `valueForKey:` on an array constructs a new array with only the values of that key of each object in the original collection. Very powerful for situations like this one.

```
 NSArray *filteredComponentGroups = // ... your filtered components

 NSArray *componentIdsFromFilteredComponentGroups = [filteredComponentGroups valueForKey: @"groupId"];
 NSPredicate *inFilteredComponentGroupsP = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"groupId IN %@", componentIdsFromFilteredComponentGroups];

 NSArray *filteredGroupItemList = [componentGroupItemList filteredArrayUsingPredicate: inFilteredComponentGroupsP];
```

Typed directly in the browser, so beware of typos.

Comment: Now you were 8 seconds faster :-) - If I understand it correctly, the necessary key is "groupId", not "componentId", but I may be wrong.